# Crystal Reports for VS 2010 Redistributable installed - and not working

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a .net project using a crystal report.  I am using VS2010 and targeting the .net 3.5 framework.  Everything works on my development machine, but not on the production web server.  I have installed the SAP Crystal Reports 32 bit redistributable package (SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET framework) on my web server.

I am still getting an exception saying "Type 'ReportDocument' is not defined."

Do I have to do anything other than install the redistributable to get my site to recognize the Crystal Reports objects such as ReportDocument?

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;" />
        <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2010.02.0713.35" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Can you post the runtime section of your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the following in the 'assemblyBinding' section either manually or by readding your references to CrystalDecision.

```
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine"    publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.2000.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.1100.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture=""/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.2000.0" newVersion="12.0.1100.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had to modify this slightly as I am using version 13 not 12, but this was the basic fix.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to put CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine as a reference in your solution.